# Read data from DynamoDB and recall with Alexa

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, alexa-skills-kit

I'm trying to create a skill with Alexa to read data from my DynamoDB table using either the scan or query function (or both).

The columns in my table are date, time and film name.

I'm new to this but I've managed to link my Lambda function to Alexa. I have also created a separate Lambda function that will recall data from my table when I configure test events, so when I input a specific date it will recall the corresponding film and time. However now i want to implement this into Alexa and am not sure how.

Here is my current code

```js
console.log('Loading function');

var AWSregion = 'us-east-1';  // us-east-1
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var dclient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

var getItems = (event, context, callback)=>{
    
    dclient.get(event.params,(error,data)=>{
        if(error){
            callback(null,"error occurerd");
        }
        else{
            callback(null,data);
        }
    });
};

exports.handler = getItems;
```

and the code i have to launch the skill in alexa is

```js
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    try {

        var request = event.request;

        if (request.type === "LaunchRequest") {
            context.succeed(buildResponse({
                speechText: "Welcome to H.S.S.M.I skill, what would you like to find",
                repromptText: "I repeat, Welcome to my skill, what would you like to find",
                endSession: false
            }));
        }


        else if (request.type === "SessionEndedRequest") {
            options.endSession = true;
            context.succeed();
        }
        else {
            context.fail("Unknown Intent type");
        }
        
        



    } catch (e) {

    }


};

function buildResponse(options) {
    var response = {
        version: "1.0",
        response: {
            outputSpeech: {
                "type": "SSML",
                "ssml": `<speak><prosody rate="slow">${options.speechText}</prosody></speak>`
            },

            shouldEndSession: options.endSession
        }
    };

    if (options.repromptText) {
        response.response.reprompt = {
            outputSpeech: {
                "type": "SSML",
                "ssml": `<speak><prosody rate="slow">${options.repromptText}</prosody></speak>`
            }
        };
    }

    return response;
}
```

I don't mind changing my table from DynamoDB to something else so long as I can recall the data.

Answer (score 1):

Please try below code,

```js
var DBHandler = require("./DBHandler")

var DBHandler = require("./DBHandler")
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    try {
        
        var request = event.request;

        if (request.type === "LaunchRequest") {
            context.succeed(buildResponse({
                speechText: "Welcome to home remedy. Please tell me what is the problem you want remedy for?",
                repromptText: "You can say for example, home remedy for headache",
                endSession: false
            }));
        }
        else if (request.type === "IntentRequest") {
            let options = {};

            if (request.intent.name === "Cinema") {



                DBHandler.getItems(ID, function (err, data) {
                    if (err) {
                        context.fail(err);

                    } else {

                        if (data.Item !== undefined) {



                            options.speechText = data.Item.YOURFIELDHERE
                            options.endSession = true;
                            context.succeed(buildResponse(options));


                        } else {
                            options.speechText = `I am Sorry, I couldn't find any data! `
                            options.endSession = true;
                            context.succeed(buildResponse(options));
                        }
                    }

                    callback(null, data)
                });



            } else if (request.intent.name === "AMAZON.StopIntent" || request.intent.name === "AMAZON.CancelIntent") {
                options.speechText = "ok, thanks for using my skill.";
                options.endSession = true;
                context.succeed(buildResponse(options));
            }

            else {
                context.fail("Unknown Intent")
            }
        }

        else if (request.type === "SessionEndedRequest") {
            options.endSession = true;
            context.succeed();
        }
        else {
            context.fail("Unknown Intent type")
        }



    } catch (e) {

    }


};


function buildResponse(options) {
    var response = {
        version: "1.0",
        response: {
            outputSpeech: {
                "type": "SSML",
                "ssml": `<speak><prosody rate="slow">${options.speechText}</prosody></speak>`
            },

            shouldEndSession: options.endSession
        }
    };

    if (options.repromptText) {
        response.response.reprompt = {
            outputSpeech: {
                "type": "SSML",
                "ssml": `<speak><prosody rate="slow">${options.repromptText}</prosody></speak>`
            }
        };
    }
    
    return response;
}
```

and DBHandler would be,

```js
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({
    region: "Location"
});

var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient()

var table = "TableName";

var getItems = (Id,callback) => {   
  
    var params = {
        TableName: table,
        Key: {
            "Id": Id
        }
    };

    docClient.get(params, function (err, data) {
        callback(err, data);
    });

};

module.exports = {
    getItems
};
```

Comment: did you add DBHandler.js as a seperate js file?

Comment: sorry i did that just before you replied, when testing my lambda function it works, and i can open the skill on alexa. Would i now need to redo my intent schema so i can find data from my table?

Comment: Hi, sorry to bother you again, is there any tutorials you know of that i can read up on to help me with my skill?

Comment: Are you ready to spend 11.99 GBP? Then buy this course https://www.udemy.com/comprehensive-alexa-skill-development-course/learn/v4/overview

Comment: yes thank you, ill give that a go and see where i get to

Comment: hi ive checked out the resource you've provided and it doesnt provide any tutorials on how to intergrate a dynamodb response to my alexa skill, would you be able to help

Comment: Hi Vijay, are you still willing to help me complete my alexa project?

Comment: can you make it tomorrow 3:00 PM?

Comment: I have commented that on Saturday and meant to connect on 3:00 PM Sunday. Today I can't connect as I would be at the office. Anyway will add you on Skype and will call whenever you are online

Comment: Hi could you kindly send me your skype id?